# HandlebarsJS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm just starting to learn Handlebars.js, I used the Handlebars.js site (http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) to help write this following snippet here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3TxVx/2/

```
var story = {
    url: "www.nytimes.com/colonizemars.html",
    text: "We finally colonized mars!"
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(object) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(
        "<a href='" + object.url + "'>" + object.text + "</a>"
    );
});

var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript);

var temp = theTemplate(story);
console.log(temp);

$(function() {
    $(document.body).append (temp);
});
```

Not sure why I get the following error when I run it:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Handlebars is very picky on the format of the data or context. I made the the following change to the story object and it worked.

```
    var data = { 
            story :  {
                url: "www.nytimes.com/colonizemars.html",
                text: "We finally colonized mars!"
            }
    };
```

So now my entire code looks like this:

```
<script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{{link story}}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(object) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString("<a href='" + object.url + "'>" + object.text + "</a>"
        );
    });

    var data = { 
            story :  {
                url: "www.nytimes.com/colonizemars.html",
                text: "We finally colonized mars!"
            }
    };

    var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript);

    var temp = theTemplate(data);
    console.log(temp);

    $(function() {
        $(document.body).append (temp);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
registerHelper('link', function(object)
```

with

```
registerHelper('link', function(text, url)
```

From the docs:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text, url) {
    text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
    url = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(url);

    var result = '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

http://handlebarsjs.com/